# Error al obtener documentos firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Tengo una colección en firebase la cual tiene unos cuantos documentos. Tengo un código en javascript el cual se conecta a esta base de datos.

```js
window.onload = inicializar();
var dbRef;
function inicializar() {
    dbRef = firebase.firestore().collection(PRODUCTOS); //dbRef contiene la referencia a mi coleccion de documentos en Firestore
    firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Codigo de Error: " + error.code);
        console.log("Mensaje de Error: " + error.message);
    });
    getAll();
}

function getAll() {
    dbRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.data());
        })
    });
}
```

El problema es que al ejecutar este codigo me da el siguente error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
marca este error en la linea 13 al inspeccionar el código en el navegador.

Espero me puedan ayudar. Desde ya muchas gracias. :)

Comment: La referencia a Firebase no se está obteniendo correctamente. Verifica que has seguido todos los pasos [que explica la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) para configurar tu entorno de forma adecuada.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la respuesta. Mi problema radicaba en la asignación de la referencia a la base de datos. Ya lo pude solucionar. Muchas gracias